# Como eliminar el interval en angular 7?

Tags: angular7

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
let secondsCounter =  interval(1000);

    secondsCounter.subscribe(n => {


       this.hora = localStorage.getItem('horaFinal');
       console.log('hora final: '+ this.hora);
      sesion = this.evaluarHoraSesion(this.hora);
      console.log(`It's been ${n} seconds since subscribing!`);
      console.log('variable de sesion: '+ sesion);

      if(sesion){
        //secondsCounter.unsubscribe();
        this.router.navigate(['login']);               
      }
    }
    );
```

Funciona bien, el detalles es como detengo el interval, intente de varias formas y basandome en una pregunta de esta pagina:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806106/how-to-stop-interval-in-angular

y nada

Comment: prueba con ls solucion pura de js , setInterval y clearInterval

Comment: Tal como dice @danit ocupa las funciones nativas set y clear Interval https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561320/end-interval-when-route-changes-in-angular-2